# Real eigenvectors with a real symetric matrix with real eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

> #### The Spectral Theorem
>
> Let $A$ be an $n×n$ real matrix.
>   Then $A$ is symetric if and only if it is orthogonally diagonalizable.

My book on linear algebra (Poole) proves the only-if part of this theorem by induction. At the induction step, an $n × n$ symmetric matrix with real eigenvalues is defined. Next they take one of these eigenvalues and say that the corresponding eigenvector is a real vector. Why is the corresponding eigenvector a real vector? Why can't it be complex.

The exact text of the proof is as follows:

> We already proved the "if" part as Theorem 5.17. To prove the "only if" implication, we proceed by induction on n. For n = 1, there is nothing to do, since a $1 × 1$ matrix is already in diagonal form. Now assume that every $k × k$ real symetric matrix with real eigenvalues is orthogonally diagonalizable. Let n = k + 1 and let A be an $n × n$ real symetric matrix with real eigenvalues.
>
> Let $ λ_{1}$ be one of the eigenvalues of A and let $v_{1}$ be a corresponding eigenvector. Then $v_{1}$ is a real vector.

Comment: The matrix will **also** have a complex eigenvector.  The point is that we can necessarily choose a real eigenvector associated with this eigenvalue.

Comment: The textbook you're using has certainly made a mistake (or at least taken liberties) in describing the eigenvectors of $A$.  Calling $v_1$ **the** corresponding eigenvector is misleading; for any eigenvector $v_1$, the multiples $\alpha v_1$ for $\alpha \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ are perfectly serviceable as eigenvectors, but distinct from $v_1$.

Comment: That was a typo of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dig deep enough, this comes down to a careful examination of whichever methods of proof your book used.  For many textbooks, this ultimately rests on the Gaussian elimination algorithm.

In any case: however your textbook has built up the fundamental facts here, you have studied eigenvalues.  So, you will have the following fact somewhere in the text:

> For a real $n \times n$ matrix $M$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $M$ is not invertible
> 2. $\det M = 0$
> 3. $Mx = 0$ has a non-trivial (real!) solution $x \in \Bbb R^n$

If $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue, then $A - \lambda I$ is a real, non-invertible matrix.  So, there is a real, non-zero vector $x$ such that $(A - \lambda I)x = 0$.  This vector $x$ satisfies $Ax = \lambda x$.